# Non-blocking OpenGL (OpenTK) Game Loop in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, opengl

I am experimenting with the idea of embedding a game inside an editor, and using an interface to allow the two to talk to each other. This is going fine, except for the fact that now, I have to make a custom game loop for when the game is docked in the editor.

The game is a Windows console application, and uses OpenTK.

- When the game is run by itself (as a standalone application), OpenTK creates a `GameWindow`, which handles its game loop internally (you call `window.Run(updateSpeed, renderSpeed)` and it starts the loop, still polling and handling window messages in the process.
- When the game is run by the editor, the game gets passed a reference to the editor's `GLControl`, and handles various events from the control.

The editor is a separate project within the same solution. It's a WPF application, and uses a `WindowsFormsHost` containing a `GLControl` for the game, which owns a space in the window, alongside panels for the various editor controls.

The problem is, that I need to be able to run the game loop from the game itself, and have that loop be capable of rendering using OpenGL. I know a little about the concepts of threading / tasks, but I also know that OpenGL contexts don't work across threads. So, if I run a standard loop in the game (when running it within the editor), the loop will block the editor and lock up the entire window. I can't create an asynchronous loop though, because then it can't call the render function, since the GL context isn't set on that thread so it raises an:

> AccessViolationException

...as soon as any GL calls are made (such as clearing the colour buffer).

In terms of how this all works in code, the game class has some private variables which determine whether or not it's embedded in the editor. When run normally, these are false/null and the game creates a window and runs normally (this all works fine). When running the editor, the editor initializes the `GLControl` and then calls a function in the game which sets the references, and tells the game it's in the editor. Then once all the WPF components are initialised, a "play" button calls the game's `Run()` function (this is the same function called by the entry-point when running as a standalone application; it just decides what to do based on the condition of the editor variables not being false/null). The WPF editor also has a "Stop" button, which will call the game's `Shutdown()` function. I would like to *potentially* implement a way to hot-reload the game's code with the editor running, eventually (maybe I'll make the game a DLL and load it that way - this isn't really important right now and might not happen, depends on whether this is in the realm of possibility; feel free to chip in about this if you think it can be done). Once the game's running, it needs to be able to update and render (preferably at different speeds - I need the update to happen 30 times per second and render at 60 times per second (of course, this will eventually take V-Sync into account)), without blocking the editor's UI.

How can I go about doing this? I imagine threads will be an absolute must, so I need a way of being able to access the GL context from within a separate thread (presumably). Any help would be greatly appreciated. If anyone needs code, tell me which parts you need, as there's quite a lot and I don't think posting it all here would be a good idea. Hopefully, you shouldn't need any though, as the project setup has been described here and currently the game itself doesn't consist of much; it just renders a white quad in the middle of the viewport for now, until I port in my code from an older version of the project; but first I need to get the basics up and running).

Answer (score 0):

After taking a break for half a day, I came back to the project to take another crack at it, and I seem to have got things working (to a roughly acceptable degree).

***What I did:***

- First of all, I changed from using a `Task` to using a `Thread`.
- Secondly, before I create the thread, I store the value of `Thread.CurrentThread`.
- Then, inside of the newly created *game loop thread*, I have a `while (Running)` loop. Each time the loop is entered, I call the game's update and render functions, as well as the `GLControl`'s `SwapBuffers()` function from within a call to: `Dispatcher.FromThread(mainThread).Invoke(( ) => { ... });`

This runs those functions from the main thread. I'm not sure exactly what's going on behind the scenes to make this work, and I'm almost certain that there's a better way to do this, but... it does work perfectly for my needs.

Here is the game loop thread code, in the hopes that this helps someone in the future (and PLEASE, if this is terrible code (and I bet it is), tell me why, and how it can be improved)

***Game loop thread code:***

```
Thread mainThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
new Thread(() =>
{
    Dispatcher.FromThread(mainThread).Invoke(() =>
    {
        Debug.LogInfo("Game loop thread started!", EditorTextColour.Green);
    });

    while (Running)
    {
        if (IsInitialized)
        {
            Dispatcher.FromThread(mainThread).Invoke(() =>
            {
                Update();
                Render();
                if (Embedded)
                {
                    EmbeddedControl.SwapBuffers();
                }
            });
        }
        Thread.Sleep(200); // TODO: Tune this using actual timing values!!
    }
}).Start();
```

***Result:***

The engine runs the game, tells it that it's embedded in an editor, and calls the game's `Run()` function. The game notices it's embedded, and chooses not to create a window, instead starting the code shown above (after calling an `Initialize()` function to ensure any needed values can be set before using them). The *game loop thread* calls the game's `Update()` and `Render()` functions **from the main thread, via the `Dispatcher`**, and sleeps after each loop. Et Voilá, we have a game running inside its very own WPF editor! Pretty neat, for a learning exercise!